# Ship classes decorated with interfaces through WCF

Tags: c#, wcf

My WCF WebService project references another project that contains some classes that are decorated with some interfaces. However, when creating the proxy, the WCF client does not decorate those classes.

How can I force the proxy to decorate the class properly, so that I can ensure that the classes implement the interfaces?

Comment: decorate your interfaces with attributes  [ServiceContract]
    [ServiceKnownType(typeof(ClassName))]
    [ServiceKnownType(typeof(List<ClassName>))]

Comment: @Hakunamatata That does not work

Comment: Did you try to use PCL to share the classes among client/server? Then there is no need to generate new classes at client side.

Comment: @LexLi Actually, the classes are DAL ones generated by Entity Framework. In our scenario and architecture, we must access those class through the WebService

Comment: You will either a) need to put them in an assembly that can be shared between the client and the service (as @LexLi suggested) or b) provide concrete implementations in the service that can be exposed as part of the metadata.  Interfaces are not serializable - there is nothing to serialize, and they're more of an OOP concept than an SOA concept.